# Turn on SVNAutoversioning for individual repository

Tags: svn, apache, auto-versioning

I'd like to enable SVNAutoversioning for one repository only. Would this work?

```
<Location /repos/>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /path/to/repositories
</Location>

<Location /repos/specific_repo/>
  SVNAutoversioning on
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
The **SVNAutoversioning** directive is an apache directive valid for the whole **Location** directive
In your (erroneous) example you would have an new "Location" without any SVN configuration in it. There is no inheritation of the parameters from one location to another. Also: which location should apache choose for accessing SVN?`Both would be valid.

You have to move your repositories with autoversioning into another location:

```
<Location /repos/>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /path/to/repositories
</Location>

<Location /repos_auto/>
  DAV svn
  SVNAutoversioning on
  SVNParentPath /path/to/auto_versioning_repositories
</Location>
```

Obviously this will break some of the checkout URLS which you have to repair with

```
svn switch --relocate
```

for pre SVN 1.7, resp.

```
svn relocate
```

for svn 1.7 clients

Comment: Is there any problem pointing both locations to the same SVNParentPath?

Comment: This would be working as long as <location>s are different, but you would enable autoversioning on ALL repos .